# Catel ServiceLocatorRegistration attribute get compile error message

Tags: attributes, service-locator, catel

I try to create automatically registering with Catel framework,

```
     [ServiceLocatorRegistration(typeof(ISalesOrderListViewModel))]
     public class SalesOrderListViewModel : ISalesOrderListViewModel
     {
     }
```

But i got this error when compile this code.
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Does Catel ServiceLocatorRegistration attribute need something I don't know?

help!!

Comment: Your code looks correct. In the unit tests, we use this:

[ServiceLocatorRegistration(typeof(IFooService))]
public class FooService : IFooService
{
}

Are you sure that this is the class causing the error?

Comment: Yes, after I remove this attribute, it complies fine. By the way, I try to find some sample code in unit test, but I don't find code like you said. I would like you tell me where I can find this unit test code.

Comment: ServiceLocatorFacts.cs => TheAutoRegisterTypesViaAttributes class

Comment: you are right, at net45 it does work, but I work with net4, it looks something not works well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find under net framework 4.5, this attribute works fine, but when I try to run this under net framework 4.0, this attribute doesn't work, which meaning I get compile error.
Mr. Geert, I don't know I should submit this to issue track or you may don't support this under net framework 4.0.